# How do I get an attribute from an object if I have the attribute name in a string?

Tags: python

```
 class a :
     b = 10
```

I have a class 'a' with attribute 'b'.

```
  o = a()
```

I create a object 'o' of class 'a'

```
  v = 'b'
```

I have another variable 'v' having the string representation of attribute 'b' of class 'a'

Now suppose I have only 'v' and '0'.
ie how can I do

```
o.v
```

How do I get the value of b ie '10'

Comment: Please look at how I changed the title. Try and write titles that describe a problem, not just name some things that you're thinking about.

Comment: Not related to the question itself, just to make sure, do you realize that `a.b` is really a class attribute, i.e. it's shared between all the instances and you can access it as `a.b` as well as `o.b` ?

Comment: Aside: while getattr/setattr can be very useful, it's also often used by newcomers to Python where most of us would use a dictionary instead.  If you find yourself needing it frequently you're probably making life harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @agf I'm Sorry for the trouble.I Was just leaving office.. couldn't think of a proper title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
getattr(o, v)
```

Comment: +1. What's the shortcut for text fillers like *Are you looking for something like this?* if the real answer is too short?

Comment: @eumiro: `<!-- I am a placeholder! Yay! -->` ;)

Comment: @eumiro: I just typed it, as evidenced by the typo. (Thanks, @minitech!)

Answer (score 5):

Use the built-in [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
getattr(o, v)
```